# Owner of postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

I'm just a Postgresql novice so excuse the ignorance, does the owner of a postgresql database automatically have all privileges to the database including all new tables, sequences etc created?

So if my application is using the a postgresql database user called app-user (and is the owner), does that mean I could do anything in that database despite the app-user only has read permission on public schema?

What I'm trying to get at, is I want one database user that has full privileges to a single database and not having to worry about any future tables being created etc.

Postgresql privileges is little confusing to me compared to MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: From [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/ddl-priv.html): *"When you create a database object, you become its owner. By default, only the owner of an object can do anything with the object. In order to allow other users to use it, privileges must be granted. (However, users that have the superuser attribute can always access any object.)"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL privileges are very logical once you get the basic idea.

Each objects carries its own *access control list* (ACL) that governs who has what privileges on it.

Each object has an owner, which is the user that created it. The owner has all privileges by default, and all other roles have no privileges (there are many exception to this latter rule, for example databases or functions). Only the owner can `ALTER` or `DROP` an object.

If an object can contain other objects (like a database can contain schemas or subscriptions, or a schema can contain tables), you need the `CREATE` privilege on that object to create objects in it.

So let's put that together:

- If you start with an empty database, all the user needs is the `CREATE` privilege on the database (which would be included in ownership). Then he can create schemas in that database. Since he is then the owner of these schemas, he has the `CREATE` privilege and can create objects in it.
- If the database you start with is not empty, then you additionally have to grant that user privileges on the existing objects (or change the ownership of these objects). Being the owner of a database does **not** imply being the owner of all objects in the database.

To answer your specific question, if `app-user` owns the database, but has no `CREATE` privilege on schema `public`, `app-user` will be able to create new schemas in the database and create objects in these schemas, but will not be able to create objects in `public`.